# How to remove a number between 2 values in a string in a list? c#

Tags: c#, list

If I have this:

```
List<string> list = new List<string>();
list.Add(dog456789);
list.Add(train123456);
list.Add(park147852);
list.Add(car236985);
```

How can I remove all numbers between 100000 and 999999 and be left with only dog ,train etc in the list?

Comment: Are `dog456789` etc. actual objects or are they meant to be strings?

Comment: They are ment to be strings i think :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming `dog456789` and other added objects are string. You can use RemoveAll method. it removes all the items where the predicate returns true.

```
Regex matchNumber = new Regex(@"\d+$");
List<string> list = new List<string>();
list.Add("dog456789");
list.Add("train123456");
list.Add("park147852");
list.Add("car236985");

list.RemoveAll(str =>
{
    int number = int.Parse(matchNumber.Match(str).Value);
    return number < 999999 && number > 100000; // if true remove
});
```

If you want to keep the items but only remove numbers the you need to use `Select` from Linq.

```
list = list.Select(str =>
{
    int number = int.Parse(matchNumber.Match(str).Value);
    if (number < 999999 && number > 100000) return matchNumber.Replace(str, "");
    else return str;
}).ToList();
```

Or use simple for loop which is better here.

```
for (int i = 0; i < list.Count; i++)
{
    int number = int.Parse(matchNumber.Match(list[i]).Value);
    if (number < 999999 && number > 100000) list[i] = matchNumber.Replace(list[i], "");
}
```

Comment: Thanks, it seems like it removes the whole list tho, i need to be left with only "dog", "train", "park" and "car".

Comment: Your original question is not very clear - it doesn't mention this. You should update it to fully explain exactly what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: Thank you so much again, i do still have one problem tho, and its probobly becasue i didn't write it but it dosn't work when i have numbers (that i want to stay in my list) which is less then 100000. eks: d1og456789 or train1|456789 i want this to return d1og and train1|.

Comment: @Leethe i fixed it.look at regex pattern. I just changed regex pattern and added $ at end. Means numbers should only match at end of string. This should work for you.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [RemoveAll](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wdka673a(v=vs.110).aspx) to remove all items that meet your condition.

Comment: The `RemoveAll` method is not LINQ, it's a method of the `List<T>` class.